# Connecting to proxy that has authentication required

Tags: c#, proxy

So I'm currently using this to connect to a proxy, but if i want to use a proxy that require authentication before using it, (username:password) , it just doesn't work/crash
It's supposed to go in this format : username:password@proxy:port
but it just doesn't work :/ anyone would know what to do?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2011/04/26/how-to-set-the-proxy-for-the-webbrowser-control-in-net.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: the code is in the link , do i really need to show it? :S

Comment: How do we know that you copied the code correctly? Also, we don't need to see _all_ the code - only the minimum amount of code necessary to reproduce the problem. Once you have reduced the code to the minimum, you may even see the problem yourself. See http://sscce.org/.